# Django send_mass_mail() limit

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, email

I'm using the `send_mass_mail()` function from the `django.core.mail module`. Does the module limit the number of receipients on one email and/or the number of emails that can be sent out?

Answer (score 2):

According to [docs.djangoproject.com](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/email/#send-mass-mail), no. The only limit would be from your email service provider.

> **Each separate element of datatuple** results in a separate email message. As in send_mail(), recipients in the same recipient_list will all see the other addresses in the email messages’ “To:” field.

> The main difference between `send_mass_mail()` and `send_mail()` is that `send_mail()` opens a connection to the mail server each time it’s executed, while `send_mass_mail()` uses a single connection for all of its messages. This makes `send_mass_mail()` slightly more efficient.